# NSInternalInconsistencyException: Invalid update in tableView with sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, rubymotion

I have a UITableView with sections from which I'm trying to delete rows. In switching to AFMotion from BubbleWrap I've started getting a few immutable array errors. Usually they are fixable by appending a mutableCopy on the object I'm altering before pushing its view controller. For the table with sections, however, I get past the frozen/immutable array error but get an `NSInternalInconsistencyException: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0`. I have seen other questions about these and have tried adding `beginUpdates`, `endUpdates`, etc. but it still won't work.

My data object is a hash that looks like this:

```
{
  "Items" => ["one", "two", "three"],
  "More"  => ["four", "five", "six"]
}
```

I pass that data to a new controller when I present it:

```
def tap_items(sender)
  controller        = ItemsController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle:nil)
  controller.data   = @data[:items].mutableCopy
  self.presentViewController(
    UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(controller),
    animated:true,
    completion: lambda {}
  )
end
```

Then in `ItemsController` my table is set up to delete rows with the following:

```
def tableView(tableView, commitEditingStyle:editingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
  if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete
    rows_for_section(indexPath.section).delete_at indexPath.row
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],
      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade)
  end
end
```

But that throws the internal inconsistency exception errors. I've also tried `data[sections[indexPath.section]].delete_at indexPath.row` instead of `rows_for_section(indexPath.section).delete_at indexPath.row`. But that doesn't change anything.

**Update: Here is the code for my tableView**

```
def viewDidLoad
  super

  @table = UITableView.alloc.initWithFrame(self.view.bounds)
  @table.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
  self.view.addSubview(@table)

  @table.dataSource = self
  @table.delegate = self
end

def sections
  data.keys.sort
end

def rows_for_section(section_index)
  data[self.sections[section_index]].mutableCopy
end

def row_for_index_path(index_path)
  rows_for_section(index_path.section)[index_path.row]
end

def tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection:section)
  sections[section]
end

def numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView)
  self.sections.count
end

def tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
  rows_for_section(section).count
end
```

Comment: I'm no Ruby expert, so I don't know exactly how this behaves... but aren't you deleting from the mutable copy of your data (as returned by rows_for_section) rather than editing the original data itself? You mentioned that you've tried changing each of those individually, but have tried deleting the entry from BOTH data and rows_for_section?

Comment: I have, but there I get `can't modify frozen/immutable array`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somehow you are not referencing the correct instance of your dataSource. You don't show where you are assigning it, i.e. `tableView.dataSource = data`, nor the code for `rows_for_section`. I'm wondering whether it has to do with the `.mutableCopy`. Is that necessary for some reason?

In my app, I pull in the dataSource directly from the tableView, i.e. `tableView.dataSource`.

Comment: Just updated with my `rows_for_section` code and the `dataSource`. Thanks!

Comment: If this was helpful don't forget to select the answer, cheers.

Comment: If I remove `.mutableCopy` from rows_for_section, I get can't modify immutable/frozen array. So that's why I put that there. I added it to the data I pass just cause I wanted to see if that would do anything.

Comment: Not sure why you would have a frozen array if you're building it with ruby.

Comment: I didn't get that until I switched from BubbleWrap to AFMotion